# Send a message to the eureka server that the client will not be available

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented such a structure:

- Two servers with Spring boot 3 - java 17.
- A spring cloud gateway server (spring-cloud.version: 2022.0.2).
- A eureka server (spring-cloud-netflix: 4.0.1).

When I want to change one of the servers, I have to kill this server (`kill -9 PID`). But it takes about 30 seconds for eureka to realize that the server is down. I do not intend to reduce the time (Because this causes me a lot of submissions and requests on the network). After eureka confirmed that the server was down(And the gateway did not send any more requests to this server), I changed my version and then started it and repeated this for the second server.

What solution do your suggest for this issue?
(I had seen this operation on the Nginx server, which was by using a "down" word)
Thank you for your guidance.

There are a lot of requests to the server and I am watching that old requests are not filled and new requests are not sent to this server until it starts again.